# how to call `this.unset()` in meteor simple schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am using autoValue to make a doc field value available conditionally by calling `this.unset()` as mentioned in the doc [simple schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue) but the field value is still showing in collection , is there any thing wrong in the following code.

```
 'checking':{
  type:String,
  optional:true,
  label:"Wheelchair Type",
  autoValue:function(){
    if(this.siblingField('type').value != "wheelchair"){
       this.unset();
  }
}
```

Comment: surely it should be `this.value.unset()`

Comment: It is showing error  `this.value.unset is not a function`

Comment: can you show your actual output vs the output you desire?

Comment: **desired output** : `{ type: 'runner'} else { type:'wheelchair',checking: 'checked' }`,  **actual output**:`{ type: 'runner',checking: 'checked' } else { type:'wheelchair',checking: 'checked' }`

Comment: @Takarii do you have any suggestions ??